# How to run parallel SQL within a reactive in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, parallel-processing

**Background:** I have a Shiny app that generates one dataframe by merging the results of several SQL queries from different databases into one dataframe.

Each SQL query is held within a function and all of the functions run once a button is pressed.

**The problem:** Two of the queries take a while to run but because Shiny is the way it is, they run in serial whereas I suppose it would be a lot faster to get them to run in parallel.

**Attempts:** I tried firstly to get each query to run asynchronously but apparently that is really for scaling an application between users rather than within session asynchronous so I've ditched that approach and tried to use parallel processing with doParallel.

I started by using the parallel processing within each function but of course that is pointless because the parallel processing doesn't chop up a SQL query and run each separately, so then I thought I should add all the functions to a list and run them with a parallel processing.

```
library(shiny)
library(doParallel)
library(dplyr)

PendingApptdf<-reactiveValues(data = data.frame()) #dataframe for the pending data
myResdf<-reactiveValues(data = data.frame()) #Results dataframe
LatestResultsdf<-reactiveValues(data = data.frame()) #Final dataframe
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Parallel SQL attempt"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
        ),

        mainPanel(
            actionBttn("LatestResults_btn",label = "Latest results",size="sm"),
            DT::dataTableOutput("LatestResultsTable")
        
        )
    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    
    #SQL number one:
    PatientPendingAppt<-function(HospNums){
        ch_PAD_PendingAppt<-odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER={*******};*******;Database=******")
        sql_PAD_PendingAppt<-paste0("SELECT * from database",HospNums)
        resultsetPAD_PendingAppt <- sqlQuery(ch_PAD_PendingAppt, sql_PAD_PendingAppt)
        resultsetPAD_PendingAppt<-unique(resultsetPAD_PendingAppt)
        odbcClose(ch_PAD_PendingAppt)
        return(resultsetPAD_PendingAppt)
    }
    
    
    
    #SQL number two:
    myRes<-function(HospNums){
        ch_PAD_myRes<-odbcDriverConnect("DRIVER={*******};*******;Database=******")
        sql_PAD_myRes<-paste0("SELECT * from database2",HospNums)
        resultsetmyRes <- sqlQuery(ch_PAD_myRes, sql_PAD_myRes)
        resultsetPAD_myRes<-unique(resultsetPAD_myRes)
        odbcClose(ch_PAD_myRes)
        return(resultsetPAD_myRes)
    }
    
    
    PendingAppt<-reactive({
        myNumber<- '123456'
        Pending<-PatientPendingAppt(myNumber)
        PendingApptdf$data<-Pending
        
    })
    
    
    myResOP<-reactive({
        myNumber<- '123456'
        myResOP1<-myRes(myNumber)
        myResdf$data<-myResOP1
        
    })
    
    
    
    
    ####Latest results datatable####
    output$LatestResultsTable = DT::renderDT({
        
        outputPar <- foreach(i = 1:2, .packages="RODBC")%dopar%{
            PendingAppt()
            mergedEnoting<-mergedEnoting()
            
            
            #merge the results here with rbind 
        }
        
        LatestResultsdf<-outputPar
            
        datatable(LatestResultsdf$data,
                  options = list(
                      dom = 't'),
        )
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But this doesn't seem to work either and it tells me that it can't find the function PendingAppt.

Why is this? Is it because it is a reactive being run inside of the parallel processing. If so then how to rectify?

How can I run the two SQL functions so that they run concurrently rather than in serial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `futures` combined with `promises` to run the two queries in parallel, see [scaling shiny with async](https://blog.rstudio.com/2018/06/26/shiny-1-1-0/).
Under SQL Server I used a `WAIT FOR DELAY` to simulate two long queries:

```
library(DBI)
library(shiny)
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multisession,workers = 2)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Async Test"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("choice",
                        "Choice",
                        choice = list('choice 1','choice 2'))
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           textOutput("data1"),
           textOutput("data2")
  
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output,session) {

    cat(nbrOfWorkers(),' workers launched \n')
    
    # first query depending on Choice
    data1 <-reactive({
        input$choice
        start <- Sys.time()
        future({
        conn <- dbConnect(***)
        dbGetQuery(conn,("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'"))
        dbDisconnect(conn)
        paste("Result from Task 1 : done in ", round(difftime(Sys.time(),start)), 's')
        }) %...>% print() })
    
    # second query depending on Choice
    data2 <-reactive({
        input$choice
        start <- Sys.time()
        future({
        conn <- Connect(***)  
        dbGetQuery(conn,("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'"))
        dbDisconnect(conn)
        paste("Result from Task 2 : done in ", round(difftime(Sys.time(),start)), 's')
        }) %...>% print() })

    output$data1 <- renderText({ data1()})
    output$data2 <- renderText({ data2()})

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

You can verify that the result of a 5s query and a 10s query is displayed in 10s and not in 15s :
[image: App output]

Comment: So there is no role for doParallel?

Comment: future handles the parallelization, see ?future::plan

Comment: Did the proposed solution answer your question?

Comment: I am having a hell of a time trying to get my head around futures. I guess it answered the question re parallelization for a single user so vote given.

Comment: @Sebastian Zeki, yes, more complex than synchronous programming ;). If I can help, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: Is it possible to unblock shiny app tabs with this method? I have 3 tabs sending different queries to db. Two tabs are blocked while one runs the query. Is it possible to unblock the rest of tabs? Each tab is written as one Shiny module. Have applied future/promise to each module server and then renderDT to req(rv$result). It works synchronously i.e. two tabs are still blocked while one works. I would like to be able to select inputs for other two tabs while one is working. Thanks!

Comment: @DragosBandur, I don't know, perhaps give it a try.

Comment: @ Waldi I am still trying different scenarios. Lastly, I have moved the future/promise inside each module and opened separate db connection for each module to no avail, two tabs still remain blocked. `Sys.getpid()` shows same process id in global env as well as inside future env. Tried different planning strategies: multisession as well as future.callr::callr and slurm. Also while inside module I don't think there is need for `reactiveValues` as the module itself acts as container. Any way, I think shiny tabs should be mutually independent ... Thanks!

Comment: @DragosBandur, I would suggest to open a dedicated question on this specific matter. Not much time on my side to try around, but others could help.

Comment: @Waldi Thanks, but I prefer discovery.